# wait command failure

Tags: shell, zsh, background-process

The script below has no other purpose than to illustrate this question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

arbitrary_pipeline () {
    shuf | tr a-z A-Z
}

tmpdir=$( mktemp -d )

mkfifo $tmpdir/{orig,alt}

{ tee $tmpdir/orig | arbitrary_pipeline > $tmpdir/alt; } &
pid=$!

paste $tmpdir/orig $tmpdir/alt

rm -rf $tmpdir

wait $pid
```

The script uses `tee` and two named pipes to split some (arbitrary) standard input into two streams, redirects one of them to an arbitrary pipeline, and passes the resulting two streams the inputs to `paste`.  Schematically:

```
STDIN --- > --.- arbitrary_pipeline -.
               \                      \
          paste `----<FIRST-ARGUMENT>  `- <SECOND-ARGUMENT> --> STDOUT
```

(In this case `arbitrary_pipeline` just shuffles its stdin, and converts it to uppercase, but, as the name implies, it could be anything.)

The script's stdout output looks fine, but the `wait` command always fails:

```
% grep -iP 'z.*s.*h' /usr/share/dict/words | /tmp/test.sh
Nietzsche   CITIZENSHIP'S
Zubeneschamali  NIETZSCHE
Zubeneschamali's    ZUBENESCHAMALI
citizenship CITIZENSHIP
citizenship's   ZUBENESCHAMALI'S
/tmp/test.sh:wait:18: pid 26357 is not a child of this shell
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

FWIW:

```
/usr/bin/env zsh --version
# zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

---

EDITS:

1. added curly braces around the `tee` pipeline, per jordanm's
   suggestion.  (Results did not change, though.)
2. replaced `&!` with `&` in response to Stéphane Chazelas' comment.  (Again, results did not change.)

Comment: Try adding braces: `{ tee $tmpdir/orig | arbitrary_pipeline > $tmpdir/alt; } &`

Comment: @jordanm: I get the same results

Comment: `&!` is _explicitely_ to disown the job! Of course `wait` will fail, that's what `&!` is for. Use `&` instead of `&!` if you still want the shell to consider the job as its child so you can wait for it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I get *exactly* the same results (at least outwardly) with `&` alone.  (I will edit my post to eliminate my stupid red herring.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before 5.0.8, `zsh` couldn't wait for already dead jobs. That was changed in 5.0.8 in 2014. See the change [there](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg01319.html).

Here, you can just redirect stderr to `/dev/null` to ignore the problem:

```
wait $pid 2> /dev/null
```

Note that in:

```
{ tee $tmpdir/orig | arbitrary_pipeline > $tmpdir/alt; } &
```

as an optimisation, `zsh` will not fork an extra process for `arbitrary_pipeline`, it will execute it in the same process as the one that runs that subshell started in background.

`paste` will not finish before it sees EOF on its stdin, its stdin being the pipe where `$pid` (and its children if any) is writing at the other end. So, it will not see eof until `$pid` (and children) has closed all its file descriptors (typically only stdout) to the writing end of the pipe. Unless `$pid` does explicitly close its stdout (which is very uncommon), that will only happen when it exits.

What that means is the `paste` will, in most cases, not exit before `$pid`, it's still a good idea to do the `wait` just in case.

Note that here, you could use a `coproc` to avoid the temporary fifos:

```
coproc arbitrary_pipeline
cat >&p | paste - /dev/fd/3 3<&p &
coproc : close
wait
```

(note that `wait` also waits for the `coproc`s).